# Is $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

> Is $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ uniformly continuous?

Plotting the function, I can see that is going to be uniformly continuos, but I don't know how to prove it.

NOTE: the function is defined only in the set $D=\{(x,y): 0 < x^2+y^2 < 1 \}$

Comment: How could you infer only using graphs?

Comment: Uniformly continuous functions have smooth and plain plots. It gives me an idea.

Comment: No,your intuition is not correct,i can take $\sqrt{x}$ on $(0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that:

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x, y) = 0$$

Hence we can define

$$
   \tilde f(x, y)= 
\begin{cases}
    f(x, y),& (x,y)\ne   (0,0)\\\\
    0,              & x=y=0
\end{cases}
$$

Notice that $\tilde f(x, y)$ is continuous on $\bar D$, which is compact, so $\tilde f(x, y)$ is uniformly continuos on $\bar D$ and as a consequence on $D$.

It remains to note that $\tilde f(x, y) \equiv f(x, y)$ on $D$

Comment: @MarkViola I'm not sure. In polar coordinates, we have $r$ in the denominator and $r^2$ in the numerator, so it must coverage to $0$, as $r \to 0$

Comment: Oops.  I misread $f$ as $f(x,y)=\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$, that is, without the square root in the denominator.  So, your analysis is fine. (+1)

Comment: Your definition of $\tilde f$ is not quite right.

Comment: @zhw. Do you mean that $(x, y) \in D$ ?

Comment: Yes, your restriction $x>0,y>0$ is strange.

Comment: Now $\tilde f$ is well defined and it proves that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $D$. Thank you all!!